# How can i RUN the Jupyter and/or google colaboratory , based visualization codes into my PHP webpage

Tags: python, php, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, visualization

How can I effectively integrate a Jupyter-based network visualization code, written in Python, into my PHP-based webpage? I've attempted to execute the Python script using shell_exec in PHP, but I'm open to alternative solutions and ideas. The Python script generates a network visualization, and I want to display this visualization on my webpage. Are there recommended practices for achieving this integration while ensuring security and flexibility in the visualization output format?

```
$scriptPath = 'C:\..\pathway_ik.py';  // Replace with the full path to your Python script

//$command = escapeshellcmd("$pythonPath $scriptPath");

$command = escapeshellcmd("$scriptPath");
$output = shell_exec($command);

echo "Script Output:<br>";
echo $output;
```

THIS WAS THE JUPYTER WIDGET WHICH I HAVE USED INN:

```
pip install biopython    
pip install ipycytoscape

import networkx as nx
import ipycytoscape as cyto
from ipywidgets import Layout
import pandas as pd
from Bio.KEGG import REST
from Bio.KEGG.KGML import KGML_parser
from Bio.KEGG.REST import *
import os
import csv
import re
import math
```